# cal_days_in_month() [function.cal-days-in-month]: invalid date

Tags: php

I want to calculate the number of days in a month. And it's appear this Warning:

```
cal_days_in_month() [function.cal-days-in-month]: invalid date.
```

Could anyone help me. :

```
$numberofday = new DateTime($month);
$numberofday = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month,$year1);
$Total=$length  x 24  x $numberofday ;
```

Comment: What's the value of $month and $year1? Can you try using a static value to see if it still has errors?

Comment: The second parameter of cal_days_in_month accepts integer values. Please convert the string value of month to integer first before passing it to the function.

Comment: any other method to calculate the numberofday without convert the string value?

Comment: Well you can use `$numberofday = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date('m', strtotime($month)),$year1);` if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cal_days_in_month()` accepts integer value for the month field, please convert the month to integer:

```
$month = "april";
$year1 = "2013";
$month = date('m', strtotime($month));
```

before using the function.

```
$numberofday = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year1);
```

alternative for `cal_days_in_month`:

```
$month = "april";
$year1 = "2013";
$numberofday = date('t', strtotime("$year1-" . date("m",strtotime($month)) . "-01"));
```

also:

```
$Total=$length  x 24  x $numberofday;
```

should be:

```
$Total=$length * 24 * $numberofday;
```

Comment: it's still wont work. :(

Comment: What's the error? Is it still coming from `cal_days_in_month()`?

Comment: yup. still appear the warning.

Comment: I added an alternative, `$numberofday = date('t', strtotime("$year1-$month-01"));` try that to see if it will work.

Comment: i used this $numberofday = date('t', strtotime("$year1-$month-01")); but it return number of days apr=31.

Comment: updated to `$numberofday = date('t', strtotime("$year1-" . date("m",strtotime($month)) . "-01"));`

Answer (score 0):

You have 'length', Should it be $length ?

Answer (score 0):

$month = 4;

$year1 = 2013;

$numberofday = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month,$year1);

echo $numberofday; //30